# In MATLAB classdef, can you define an "any_function"?

Tags: matlab, class, object, methods

In MATLAB 's classdef, can you define a method that executes **any_function** that has called it?

For example, say I have defined this custom class type in MATLAB:

```
classdef custfloat

    properties
      value = double(0);   % Double value
    end

    methods


        function obj = custfloat(v, ex, mant)

            obj.value = ........blah blah blah;
        end


        function v = any_function(arg1,arg2)

            v = any_function(arg1.value, arg2.value);
        end

    end
end
```

So as long as `any_function` is defined for two doubles, it will work, no matter what `any_function` actually is.

Does this makes sense?

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Comment: I also do not understand the question.  Could you please provide an example of how the `any_function` method would be used in practice and any expected output or behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question means exactly, but I think you can get what you're looking for my just subclassing `double`.

For example, here's a simple class that extends `double` to create something that's like `double`, but has a unit as well (for example metres or seconds).

```
classdef custDouble < double

    properties

        unit

    end

    methods

        function obj = custDouble(v, u)
            % Do something with exponents and mantissas instead if you like,
            % I can't remember floating point stuff well enough for this
            % example
            obj = obj@double(v);
            obj.unit = u;
        end

        function val = myExtraMethod(obj)

            val = custDouble(obj*2, obj.unit);

        end

    end

end
```

You can now create a `custDouble` like this:

```
>>a = custDouble(2, 'm')
a = 
  custDouble with properties:

    unit: 'm'
  double data:
     2
```

You can call your extra methods:

```
>> b=a.myExtraMethod
b = 
  custDouble with properties:

    unit: 'm'
  double data:
     4
```

and you can call any regular function that applies to doubles:

```
>> sqrt(a)
ans =
       1.4142
```

Note, though, that `sqrt` here will return a `double`, not a `custDouble` - it's just acting on the underlying `double`. If you wanted regular functions like `sqrt` to return a `custDouble`, you'd need to overload them with a method on `custDouble` that would behave in the appropriate way (such as, for example, calling `builtin('sqrt',...)` on the underlying `double`, then constructing the right unit, then putting them together into a `custDouble` - in the way that `myExtraMethod` above does).

Search the documentation for "Subclassing MATLAB Built-In Types" for more information.

Comment: nice simple subclassing example which gave me lots of idea. Thanks :-)